# React Redux , value from reducer showing undefined on console.log

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

This is my shideshow.jsx file, am trying to access the value of this.props.currentSlideIndex, inside componentDidMount() and it's returning null. By the way, currentSlideIndex is being returned from mapStateToProps, below. In the below case, am able to access picStatus from mapStateToProps but not slideIndex, though both reducers seem to be implemented exactly in the same manner.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from '../stylesheets/style.module.css';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-css-transition';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changePic, slideIndex, startSlides } from '../actionFire';
import slidePic1 from '../images/slidepic1.webp';
import slidePic2 from '../images/slidepic2.webp';
import slidePic3 from '../images/slidepic3.webp';
import slidePic4 from '../images/slidepic4.webp';
import slidePic5 from '../images/slidepic5.webp';

class SlideShow extends Component {
  state = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    // slideIndex: 1,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(' slide index is ' + this.props.picStatus);
    if (!this.props.slideStatus) {
      setInterval(() => {
        //this.setState({ pic: !this.state.changePic });
        this.props.changePic();
        // console.log(this.state.changePic);
        if (this.props.picStatus != true) {
          if (this.props.currentSlideIndex == 5) this.props.slideIndex();
          else this.props.slideIndex();
        }
      }, 4000);
      //this.setState({ startSlides: true });
      this.props.startSlides();
    }
  }

  render() {
    function GetFirstImage() {
      return <img src={slidePic1} width="100%" height="300px"></img>;
    }
    function GetSecondImage() {
      return <img src={slidePic2} width="100%" height="300px"></img>;
    }
    function GetThirdImage() {
      return <img src={slidePic3} width="100%" height="300px"></img>;
    }
    function GetFourthImage() {
      return <img src={slidePic4} width="100%" height="300px"></img>;
    }
    function GetFifthImage() {
      return <img src={slidePic5} width="100%" height="300px"></img>;
    }
    function GetImage(slideNum) {
      switch (slideNum) {
        case 1:
          return <GetFirstImage></GetFirstImage>;
          break;
        case 2:
          return <GetSecondImage></GetSecondImage>;
          break;
        case 3:
          return <GetThirdImage></GetThirdImage>;
          break;
        case 4:
          return <GetFourthImage></GetFourthImage>;
          break;
        case 5:
          return <GetFifthImage></GetFifthImage>;
          break;
      }
      return <GetFifthImage></GetFifthImage>;
    }
    return (
      <div className={styles.slideshowContainer}>
        <CSSTransition
          in={this.props.picStatus}
          timeout={4000}
          classNames={{
            enter: styles['slidePics-enter'],
            enterActive: styles['slidePics-enter-active'],
            exit: styles['slidePics-exit'],
            exitActive: styles['slidePics-exit-active'],
          }}
          unmountOnExit={true}
          mountOnEnter={true}
        >
          <GetImage slideNum={this.props.currentSlideIndex}></GetImage>
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    picStatus: state.changePic,
    slideStatus: state.startSlides,
    currentSlideIndex: state.slideIndex,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    changePic: () => dispatch(changePic()),
    startSlides: () => dispatch(startSlides()),
    slideIndex: () => dispatch(slideIndex()),
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SlideShow);
```

Below is the file from where my action fired i.e actionFire.js:-

```
export { changePic } from './actions/changePicAction';
export { startSlides } from './actions/startSlidesAction';
export { slideIndex } from './actions/slideIndexAction';
```

Below is the slideIndexAction.js file:

```
import { SLIDE_INDEX } from './actionConstants';

export const slideIndex = () => {
  return {
    type: SLIDE_INDEX,
  };
};
```

Below is actionConstants.js

```
export const CHANGE_PIC = 'CHANGE_PIC';
export const START_SLIDES = 'START_SLIDES';
export const SLIDE_INDEX = 'SLIDE_INDEX';
```

And most importantly slideIndexReducer.js file

```
import { SLIDE_INDEX } from '../actions/actionConstants';
const initialState = { slideIndex: 1 };

const slideIndexReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SLIDE_INDEX:
      return { ...state, slideIndex: state.slideIndex + 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default slideIndexReducer;
```

Here is my store.js:-

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import changePicReducer from './reducers/changePicReducer';
import slideIndexReducer from './reducers/slideIndexReducer';
import startSlidesReducer from './reducers/startSlidesReducer';

const redux = require('redux');
const combineReducers = redux.combineReducers;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  startSlidesReducer: startSlidesReducer,
  changePicReducer: changePicReducer,
  slideIndexReducer: slideIndexReducer,
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how you create your redux store (createStore). In general mapStateToProps looks more like this if you combineReducers.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ startSlidesReducer, changePicReducer, slideIndexReducer }) => {
  return {
    picStatus: changePicReducer.changePic,
    slideStatus: startSlidesReducer.startSlides,
    currentSlideIndex: slideIndexReducer.slideIndex,
  };
};
```

Comment: well , am trying to combine the reducers inside store itself, what shall i mention in the createStore() as a parameter.

Comment: I added a new store.js  . Please take a look above.

Comment: i've changed my mapStateToProps above according to your createStore